# React Native Expo 49 not playing sound

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, audio, expo

I have created the following react hook to play sound

```js
import { Audio } from 'expo-av'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import alarmSound from '../assets/sounds/alarm-clock.mp3'

export function useSound() {
  const sound = useRef<Audio.Sound | null>(null)

  async function playSound() {
    try {
      console.log('Loading Sound')
      sound.current = new Audio.Sound()

      await sound.current.loadAsync(alarmSound)
      console.log('Playing Sound')
      await sound.current.replayAsync()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log('Unloading Sound')
      if (sound.current) {
        sound.current.unloadAsync()
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return { playSound }
}
```

I am not getting any error in the console but the sound does not play. Here is a repository with the code setup.

Am i missing some configuration required to be able to play sounds. Are there any permissions being missed here.

https://github.com/jsbisht/playsound-test/tree/main